# Perl DBI without accessing the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, perl, dbi

I'm  creating a set of SQL `INSERT` statements for a database that doesn't exist yet, and I'm saving them to file.

How can I use Perl's powerful DBI module to create those INSERT statements without accessing a specific database. In particular, it looks like using the `$dbh->quote()` function requires that I instantiate `$dbh` with a connection to a database.

Comment: SQL is just text... create the query strings and save them. No need to involve DBI. DBI's quote() is usually just a passthrough to the database's own quoting function, so it can't be done without a DB connection, otherwise DBI won't know which drive's quote function to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the actual `quote()` behaviour isn't always a portable characteristic, so each driver will do them differently. Unless you connect to a driver, you don't know which quoting format to use in practice. (There is one module that might do this without a connection, `DBIx::Abstract`, but it is not especially current.).

The `quote()` method is actually implemented by the corresponding driver class, in the `DBD::*` namespace. You *might* attempt to load the driver you need and call the function directly (see http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/lib/DBI/DBD.pm#Writing_DBD::Driver::db::quote) but this feels grubby.

I'd still make a `DBI` connection, if only so that you get the right format of quoting. You don't need to actually send it any statements, but then you do know that the quoting format will be correct for the database you will use.

Answer (score 3):

From [`DBI::quote`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#quote):

> For most database types, at least those that conform to SQL standards, quote would return 'Don''t' (including the outer quotation marks). For others it may return something like 'Don\'t'

That is, the behavior of `DBI::quote` varies from database to database, and it doesn't make sense to call it in a database-independent way.

Make a trivial connection to a database of the same type you are writing for, or learn your database's quoting conventions and implement a `quote` method yourself. See the [DBI source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TIMB/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm) for a reference implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would use DBI by specifying a database like so:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db_name;host=127.0.0.1");
```

However, your database does not yet exist so you cannot connect to it. You can use DBI **without** specifying a database like so:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:;host=127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use DBD::CSV or DBD::AnyData as a dummy database. SQLite is good for this purpose, too.

A hidden advantage of using SQLite here is that it's a semi-real database, and will tend to make you write code in a way that's decoupled from any specific database.

Answer (score 0):

According to `perl -MDBI -E 'say join(q{,},DBI->available_drivers);'`
in clean Debian chroot with only DBI (package "libdbi-perl") installed the following drivers are available right away:

```
DBM,ExampleP,File,Gofer,Proxy,Sponge
```

The minimum DBI connect statement that works for me is

```
my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:DRIVER:");  # DRIVER is one of [DBM,File,ExampleP,Sponge,mysql,SQLite]
```

That is enough to use `$dbh->quote()` with no database whatsoever.

*DBM* and *File* escape q{**'**} as q{**\'**} ("*mysql*" style);
*ExampleP* and *Sponge* escape: q{**'**} as q{**''**} ("*SQLite*" style).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
DBD::_::db->quote()
```

To access the quote function without setting up a database handle. I don't believe it is specific to MySQL though.