# Can I use DBD::mysql quote() function without a database connection?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm writing a .sql file using Perl, not writing to the mysql database directly.  I need to quote the strings in that file.  Looks like the $dbh-quote() method does what I want.  Except that I can't figure out how to use it without a database connection.  I'd make a dummy connection, but I can't seem to do this without a database running, and the machine that is going to run this cron job won't have one.

This question is similar: [Perl DBI without accessing the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670102/perl-dbi-without-accessing-the-database) and the accepted answer states that "You might attempt to load the driver you need and call the function directly", which is what I would like to do, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670102/perl-dbi-without-accessing-the-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the answer is a resounding "you can't do it".  In any case here is a quote function I whipped up according to the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html about what needs to be quoted.

My input is UTF-8, perl stores strings in UTF-8 internally, my output is UTF-8, and my database is UTF-8.  Given that the character set is consistent, I shouldn't need to worry to much about it for escaping purposes.

```
sub quote(){
    my ($s) = @_;
    $s =~ s/\\\\/\\/g;
    $s =~ s/\'/\\'/g;
    $s =~ s/\"/\\"/g;
    $s =~ s/\x08/\\b/g;
    $s =~ s/\n/\\n/g;
    $s =~ s/\r/\\r/g;
    $s =~ s/\t/\\t/g;
    $s =~ s/\x1A/\\Z/g;
    return $s;
}
```

I tested this function and it appears to do what I want.  Too bad something like this isn't accessible from a library where it is already written.

Comment: I don't get why you need to escape something, unless you intend to run it on the database.  If you want to run it on the database, why can't you have a database connection established before you escape it, since you want to run it anyway?

Comment: The file gets copied off the production machine to get imported into a backend database.

Comment: so escape it when you import it :) [I guess you have no power over import process?]

Comment: The import process is: "cat file.sql | mysql ".   To escape on that end, I would need to write extra code and use some data interchange format in between like CSV that would have its own escaping rules.  I agree that writing your own escaping function is silly and prone to introduce bugs.  I wish there were an easy way to access this method from the widely used library.

Answer (score 4):

Reliable quoting requires that the driver understand the character set/collation of the connection as escaping varies based on that information.

This is why in PHP mysql_escape_string() was replaced with mysql_real_escape_string(), which uses the database connection properties to properly escape input strings.

Comment: My character set is UTF-8 and my collation is UTF8_BIN.  I still need to escape without a database connection.  Can a dummy connection be created with this information?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're going to have to figure out what `quote` does and implement it yourself. Not having access to a real DB connection is likely going to be a show-stopper.